# no values on y-axis and x-axis when making boxplot

Tags: boxplot, axis

I want to make a simple boxplot of predictions (from 0 to 0.89), but don't see why there are no values for y-axis.

This is my commando used:

> boxplot(dataset_validatie$predictions)

This is my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktp7t.png)

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? What is the shape of your data? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add something like this to your code, setting limits to your x, y axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('My plot')
ax.set_xlim(-10, 100)

top = 40
bottom = -5
ax.set_ylim(bottom, top)

ax.boxplot(data)
plt.show()
```

For some demos, please find the official site [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py)